# How to export n number columns as headings for PDF in Java?

Tags: java, pdf

Can anyone tell me how to export *n* number columns as headings for PDF in Java?

Actually user uploads a file in CSV. I need to export that file into PDF. The problem is if the CSV file has 1000 columns as headings then how to handle while exporting to PDF.

**Edit:** Yeah I am asking how to implement the layout, means we can't put all 1000 columns as headings in one page... can we add scroller for pdf page?

**Edit2:** I am using itext for pdf generation. How can I find the max exceed limit. No problem if horizontal scrolling occurs. The rows will be also in thousands. Here I am  able to generate the pdf file but if it exceeds more than 8 or 10 it the columns are coming together they were mixing so to avoid that how can I produce a horizontal scroller?

Comment: Are you asking what the layout should look like or how to **implement** the layout?

Comment: What tools are you using to create the PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are few things which should be considered.

1. Find out the maximum supported pdf page width, since you cant exceed this if its a limit.
2. Change your requirement if you want to include 1000 columns in pdf page, since user will be annoyed by horizontal scrolling.
3. If your individual column have say 10 to 15 rows/records, you can add your columns one after another in vertical position.

Comment: i am using itext for pdf generation how can i find the max exceed limit. no problem if horizontal scrolling occurs. the rows will be also in thousands. here i am able to generate the pdf file but if it exceeds more than 8 or 10 it the columns are coming together they were mixing so to avoid that how can i produce a horizontal scroller

Comment: @bharat: Here is answer to size .. "http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/What-is-the-maximum-page-size-for-PDF-in-iText-td2150839.html". I tried to generate the file and page size was 200cm * 200cm around 200 columns. May be you can try increasing the page width.